# Loop for assign the ports number to tomcat nodes

Tags: bash

I would like to create a script to create a certain number of Tomcat nodes and automatically assign shutdown, `HTTP` and `ajp` ports as the following schema:

```
tomcat_a
shutdown port 8001
http port 8081
ajp port 8011 


tomcat_b
shutdown port 8002
http port 8082
ajp port 8012


tomcat_n
shutdown port 8009
http port 8089
ajp port 8019
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? In most cases I would use systemd for this instead of a shell script.

Comment: Hi Jordanm, I use centos 7 and 8, My problem is that the script create correctly tomcat nodes but the port variables go to overwrite so all ports  in server.xml are the last of range